# Why surface tension direction cannot be downwards in direction when considered the surface of fluid?

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, molecules

Like in this figure we see that the surface molecules have a net downward force to all of these so should any force which we made along a line on the surface the force be downwards ? Why the surface tension is parallel to the surface ? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of a surface with unsatisfied bonds produces an energy penalty. This results in an internal [Laplace pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation), an increase in the chemical potential of the system, and a resistance to increasing the surface area: the surface tension. Since you'd apply a force parallel to the surface to extend the area, as shown below, the corresponding restoring force is also parallel to the surface.

[image]

Comment: Sir i got you point but then why in textbooks they first describe about the downward force on surface molecules while explaining surface tension ?

Comment: I can’t really speculate on the motives of an unknown textbook, but people have indicated that [this review of the topic](https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/why-is-surface-tension-a-force-parallel-to-the-interface) is useful. See also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150836/why-is-surface-tension-parallel-to-the-interface).

Comment: Thanks Sir it was really useful

Answer (score 1):

Its a little like the definition of friction.  The force components parallel to the surface are called the surface tension. The downward component is what works against evaporation.

Comment: Hmm i see Sir understood